# Can I take plain HTML snapshot of Angular index page when it's loaded in DOM [Angular template to static HTML]?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, gruntjs

I am working on feature in which I want to take current loaded angular page plain HTML snapshot. I have used grunt **html-snapshot** plugin to take HTML snapshots previously but it's static process with command line manual way. I need write script/client side code which will take snapshot of it and deliver plain HTML code as output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple workaround:

```
$http.get('/').then(function(response) {
    var raw_html = response.data; // full html
});
```

Comment: I don't want whole angular single page HTML as it is, when we run SPA(single page application) angular compiler will executes all angular expression & load data into DOM. I want to take HTML snapshot when SPA loaded in DOM.